# how to make checkmark to be selected depending on the array in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am having array in which selected name will be stored and passed to before view controller and when ever i need to go previous view controller then the previously selected check mark needs to be selected but here it is enabling the last selected element only the problem is if i select three then it is not selecting three it is check marking only the last element but i need the three selected can anyone help me how to make the check mark to be selected for three elements ?

```
protocol ArrayToPass: class {
    func selectedArrayToPass(selectedStrings: [String])
}
class FilterSelectionViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var productName = [String]()
    var productprice = [String]()
    var imageArray = [String]()
    var idArray = [Int]()
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOYOrkIOSq?indent=2"
    var values = [String]()
    var selected: Bool?
    var delegate: ArrayToPass?
    var nameSelection: Bool?
    var namesArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.downloadJsonWithURL()
        tableDetails.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        tableDetails.isHidden = true
        tableDetails.dataSource = self
        tableDetails.delegate = self
        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Apply", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(applyBarButtonActionTapped(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
        tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableDetails.rowHeight = 60
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func applyBarButtonActionTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!){
        self.delegate?.selectedArrayToPass(selectedStrings: values)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    func downloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSArray {
                for item in jsonObj! {
                    if let itemDict = item as? NSDictionary{
                        if let name = itemDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                            self.productName.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let price = itemDict.value(forKey: "value") {
                            self.productprice.append(price as! String)
                        }
                        if let image = itemDict.value(forKey: "img") {
                            self.imageArray.append(image as! String)
                        }
                        if let id = itemDict.value(forKey: "id") {
                            self.idArray.append(id as! Int)
                        }
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productName.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterSelectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterSelectionCell
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        tableDetails.isHidden = false
        cell.brandProductName.text = productName[indexPath.row]
        if nameSelection == true{
            if namesArray.count != 0 {
                print(namesArray)
                for name in namesArray{
                    if productName[indexPath.row].contains(name){
                        print(productName[indexPath.row])
                        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                    }
                    else {
                        cell.accessoryType = .none
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        selected = false
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
                print("\(productName[indexPath.row])")
                values = values.filter{$0 != "\(productName[indexPath.row])"}
                selected = true
            }
            else{
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
        if selected == true{
            print(values)
        }
        else{
            getAllTextFromTableView()
        }
        print(values)
    }
    func getAllTextFromTableView() {
    guard let indexPaths = self.tableDetails.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { // if no selected cells just return
    return
    }

    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        values.append(productName[indexPath.row])
    }
    }
```

[here is the image for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRxtT.png)

Comment: How are you sending array back to the first view controller ?

Comment: i am using protocol to pass data to another view controller @AravindAR

Comment: here when i come back from first view controller to previous i need to made check mark the previously selected and in order to select other more brands @AravindAR

Comment: have you reload the table after send the data back?

Comment: what' s the need of reloading table view here ? @Tj3n

Comment: check my complete code here i posted in question

Comment: @user could you please share the code of how you are sending the array to the previous controller using protocol and also the code of the protocol function

Comment: @AravindAR please check i had posted the code i posted above

Comment: If  you dont reload the table, the changes wont appear in your table

Comment: depending on the values array in filter view controller when i go to the filter selection i need to make checkmark the selected ones so i had posted the remaining code which used in filter selection view controller @AravindAR

Comment: @user Thanks for sharing the code but from where are you calling the function selectedArrayToPass from filter selection viewcontroller so that the values will get reflected in the filter ViewController

Comment: yes @AravindAR depending on the names contained in the array i need to make checkmark the names row and in need to add some more

Comment: @user I just wanted you to share the code of how you are calling the selectedArrayToPass function

Comment: func selectedArrayToPass(selectedStrings: [String]){
        selected = true
        values = selectedStrings
    } this is the function u had asked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically do not manipulate the view (the cell). Use a data model.

```
struct Product {
    let name : String
    let value : String
    let img : String
    let id : Int

    var selected = false

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        self.name = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.value = dict["value"] as? String ?? ""
        self.img = dict["img"] as? String ?? ""
        self.id = dict["id"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}
```

And **never use multiple arrays as data source** . That's a very bad habit.

Declare the data source array as

```
var products = [Product]()
```

Parse the JSON data and do a (better) error handling

```
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil { print(error!); return }
        do {
            if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                self.products = jsonObj.map{ Product(dict: $0) }                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

in `cellForRow...` assign the name to the label and set the checkmark depending on `selected`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterSelectionCell", for: indexPath)

    let product = products[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = product.name
    cell.accessoryType = product.selected ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelect...` toggle `selected` and reload the row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selected = products[indexPath.row].selected
    products[indexPath.row].selected = !selected
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

---

To get all selected items is very easy, too.

```
let selectedItems = products.filter{ $0.selected }
```

or get only the names

```
let selectedNames = products.filter{ $0.selected }.map{ $0.name }
```

There is no need at all to get any information from the **view**. The **controller** gets the information always from the **model** and uses tableview data source and delegate to update the **view**.

If you want to pass data to another view controller pass `Product` instances. They contain all relevant information.

Comment: from the model u r getting data fine but first i need to send the whole data to table view in which i will be selecting some data but here the array which is empty as mentioned after selecting then the data will be there in the array as u said objects array

Comment: Your design is very cumbersome. Don't use temporary arrays like `namesArray`. You can do everything with the model. `cellForRow` is only for updating the UI, nothing else.

Comment: whatever u r saying was fine but as i was trainee i am unable to understand completely but i understood that never not to manage with view everything try to manage with model class u r saying @Vadian

Comment: if possible can u please provide a sample project which manages by using a model not on the view @vadian

Comment: The code in the answer contains all components. It's pretty straightforward.  Instead of `productName`  (`[String]`) use the model and create the data source array with the initializer of the model passing the strings. Replace the cell identifier with your identifier.

Comment: but productName[string] was getting from json @vadian

Comment: I updated the answer with code whose naming matches the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot then for passing data names how to pass it as strings @vadian

Comment: See the last code snippet. If you want to pass all names remove `filter { ... }`

Comment: kk got it but my requirement is if i passed the selected strings after moving from filter selection view controller to filter view controller then if the user needs to select more brands the previously selected brands needs to make check mark selected  after moving from filter view controller to filter selection view controller @vadian

Comment: As mentioned before rather than passing the strings pass the `Product` instances, update the `selected` property respectively and reload the table view.

Comment: where to update the selected property and to reload the table view ?

Comment: Update in `filter view controller` reload when coming back.

Comment: sorry if u don't understand my question what ever the names which i selected previously that i need to make check mark for that names when i go back again @vadian

Comment: *Sorry if you don't understand my* answer. If you are using the model the `selected` information is stored in the `Product` instances. Just reload the table view.

Comment: that means after moving from that view controller also the data will be stored in product instances ? @vadian

Comment: Basically yes. However if you are passing the same data between controllers use a class rather than a struct to get reference semantics.

Comment: when after closing app then only the data will be cleaned or what ?

Comment: The data does not persist during multiple app launches. If you need that you need a local storage.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my questions with patience and u r really a awesome developer i had ever seen @vadian

Comment: Hello sir can you plz help me to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212064/how-to-set-enabled-checkimage-in-tableview-based-on-the-selected-cells/48212363?noredirect=1#comment83444984_48212363 i'm really very newbie to this scenario as i'm doing very first project.