# Load Checkmarks in Tableview for previously selected rows(approved users)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, userdefaults

Right now I can add checkmarks to the table of choice selected using your approach vadian. I also added the `Boolean("selected")` in my data class. What I dont get is how to save the boolean selected for each row with UserDefaults or than how to load this in cell for row at table. Do I need to even touch `didload` section?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? TableCell else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
                  let product = products[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = product.selected ? .checkmark : .none

return cell   }



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? TableCell else {



        return UITableViewCell()
    }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{ 

    var selected = products[indexPath.row].selected
    products[indexPath.row].selected = !selected
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

    if selected != true {print("selected", indexPath.row, selected )}
    else {print("selected", indexPath.row, selected )}

    selected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add a property `var approved : Bool` to your data model
- Update the property in the model when the selection changes and reload the row.
- In `cellForRow` set the checkmark depending on the property

  ```
  ...
  let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myfeedTVC", for: indexPath) as! MyFeedTVC
  let user = userDataArray[indexPath.row]
  cell.accessoryType = user.approved ? .checkmark : .none  
  ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to response I really appreciate it. so add "var approved : Bool" in the viewdidload section or above?   How do I update the property in the model when the selection changes? I am guessing I use didselectrow to somehow set the bool of each? Not sure how to than make it reload that row. Does it do that automatically?

Comment: No, you have to add the property to your data model (the items in the data source array). Each item has it's own `approved` value. You can reload a single row with `tableView.reloadRows...` and you have to do that explicitly in `didSelect` (and maybe also in `didDeselect`)

Comment: Can you show me how to do the 1st and 2nd bullets. I think I get what you are doing on the 3rd since you provided code showing me. :)

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397812/how-to-make-checkmark-to-be-selected-depending-on-the-array-in-swift-3/46398755#46398755

Comment: It is possible to use the technique in my question? Since I am able to load successfully  which index path row is selected using userdefaults, can I possibly save instead a string or boolean "true" and append it to the array instead of using the indexpath.row so instead of [0,1] i would load ["true", "true"] . Than if indexpath.row = true, show checkmark otherwise show no checkmark??